# Dynamically place shapes on the screen in a certain position on button press - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is a previous question I asked but I am editing it to make it easier to help.

I am trying to create an app where you drag around a `Circle()` on a grid, and it tracks the (x,y) coordinate of that `Circle()`. My goal is to place that `Circle()` in the (x,y) position, leave it there, and generate a new `Circle()` to move around now.

Here is the code...

```
struct GridView: View {

//tracking position and boundary
@State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
@State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
@State private var parentRect: CGRect = .zero
@State private var childRect: CGRect = .zero

//convert negative y value to positive and positive to negative
@State public var xVal: Int = 0
@State public var yVal: Int = 0

@State public var questionCount: Int = 1

//boundary for eisenhower matrix
func correctPostion() {
    print(self.currentPosition)
    if self.currentPosition.width > 200 {
        self.currentPosition.width = 200
    }
    if self.currentPosition.height > 200 {
        self.currentPosition.height = 200
    }
    if self.currentPosition.width < -200 {
        self.currentPosition.width = -200
    }
    if self.currentPosition.height < -200 {
        self.currentPosition.height = -200
    }
}

var body: some View {
    return
        ZStack {
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Text("current position: \n(X: \(xVal) Y: \(yVal))")
                    .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: 75)
                    .font(.title)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                
                Button(action: {
                    //TODO: place circle
                    
                    //increase number of circles
                    self.questionCount += 1
                    
                    //reset the values
                    self.currentPosition = .zero
                    self.newPosition = .zero
                    self.xVal = 0
                    self.yVal = 0
                    
                }, label: {
                    Circle()
                        .overlay(
                            Text("Place")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .bold()
                                .foregroundColor(.white))
                })
                .frame(width: 75, height: 75, alignment: .center)
                .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height - 100)
            }
            
            VStack{
                ZStack {
                    //My attempt at creating multiple Circles() based on the count
                    //of questions which increases on the button press
                    ForEach(0 ..< questionCount, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Circle()
                            .overlay(Text("\(questionCount)").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white))
                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
                            .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $childRect))
                    // end of my attempt
                            
                            //ability to drag and track the position of the circle
                            .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                                        
                                        self.correctPostion()
                                    }
                                    .onEnded { value in
                                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                                        
                                        self.correctPostion()
                                        
                                        xVal = Int(self.currentPosition.width)
                                        yVal = Int(self.currentPosition.height) - (Int(self.currentPosition.height) * 2)
                                        
                                        self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                                    }
                            
                            )
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                .border(Color.black, width: 3)
                .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $parentRect))
               
            }
            
        }
}
```

}

I want to place the `Circle()` in the `xVal` and `yVal` position and leave it there when I press the button, and then generate a new `Circle()` that I can do the same thing with.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were my project, I'd refactor this further to move each circle into its own view, but this should get you started. The basic concept is to store an array of circles (I've made a type called `PlacedCircle`) and render those alongside the current circle. Instead of using a variable to count the questions, you can just use the size of the placed circle array.

```
struct PlacedCircle {
    var id = UUID()
    var number: Int
    var position: CGSize
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    //tracking position and boundary
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var parentRect: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var childRect: CGRect = .zero

    //convert negative y value to positive and positive to negative
    @State public var xVal: Int = 0
    @State public var yVal: Int = 0
    
    @State public var placedCircles : [PlacedCircle] = []  //<-- Here

    //boundary for eisenhower matrix
    func correctPostion() {
        print(self.currentPosition)
        if self.currentPosition.width > 200 {
            self.currentPosition.width = 200
        }
        if self.currentPosition.height > 200 {
            self.currentPosition.height = 200
        }
        if self.currentPosition.width < -200 {
            self.currentPosition.width = -200
        }
        if self.currentPosition.height < -200 {
            self.currentPosition.height = -200
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        return
            ZStack {
                
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    Text("current position: \n(X: \(xVal) Y: \(yVal))")
                        .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: 75)
                        .font(.title)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.placedCircles.append(PlacedCircle(number: placedCircles.count + 1, position: currentPosition)) //<-- Here
                        
                        //reset the values
                        self.currentPosition = .zero
                        self.newPosition = .zero
                        self.xVal = 0
                        self.yVal = 0
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Circle()
                            .overlay(
                                Text("Place")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .bold()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white))
                    })
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75, alignment: .center)
                    .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height - 100)
                }
                
                VStack{
                    ZStack {
                        //The current circle
                        Circle()
                            .overlay(Text("\(placedCircles.count + 1)").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white))
                        .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .offset(x: currentPosition.width, y: currentPosition.height)
                            .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $childRect))

                        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                                .onChanged { value in
                                    self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                                    
                                    self.correctPostion()
                                }
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                                    
                                    self.correctPostion()
                                    
                                    xVal = Int(self.currentPosition.width)
                                    yVal = Int(self.currentPosition.height) - (Int(self.currentPosition.height) * 2)
                                    
                                    self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                                }
                        
                        )
                        
                        ForEach(placedCircles, id: \.id) { (placed : PlacedCircle) in
                            Circle()
                                .overlay(Text("\(placed.number)").font(.title).foregroundColor(.white))
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .offset(x: placed.position.width, y: placed.position.height)
                                //.background(GeometryGetter(rect: $childRect))
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 3)
                    .background(GeometryGetter(rect: $parentRect))
                   
                }
                
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm at that late beginner stage to SwiftUI and this answer was perfect. Thank you so much for spending your time helping me. Sorry I can't upvote, my reputation isn't high enough.